# Incorrect work memcached + docker-compose: returns None

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, memcached

I need your help. I'm trying to use memcached + docker-compose but I'm getting `None`. I did port forwarding web with memcached. Base cache is given 11211 port.

What am I doing wrong?

View.py example

```
from django.core.cache import cache

def show_category(requests):
categorys_name = CategoryNews.objects.all()
cache_key = 'category_names'
cache_time = 1800
result = cache.get(cache_key)
print(result)
if result is None:
    result = categorys_name
    cache.set(cache_key, result, cache_time)
    return render(requests, 'home_app/category.html', {'categorys_name':categorys_name})
return print('No none')
```

settings

```
CACHES = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
    'LOCATION': '0.0.0.0:11211',
 }
}
```

Docker-compose

```
sersion: '3'

services:
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres

  web:
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/app
    build: ./testsite
    entrypoint: ./docker-entrypoint.sh
    volumes:
      - ./testsite:/var/app
    expose:
      - "80"
      - "11211"
    depends_on:
      - db

    ngnix:
      restart: always
      build: ./ngnix
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      volumes:
        - ./testsite/static:/staticimage
        - ./testsite/media:/mediafilesh
      depends_on:
        - web

    memcached:
      image: memcached:latest
      entrypoint:
        - memcached
        - -m 64
      ports:
        - "11211:11211"
      depends_on:
        - web
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the port on your memcached container and use `memcached` as `LOCATION` in your cache config. I think you have a misconception about `expose` and `ports`:

**EXPOSE:** *Expose ports without publishing them to the host machine (YOUR COMPUTER) - they’ll only be accessible to linked services (BETWEEN CONTAINERS). Only the internal port can be specified.*

**PORTS:** *Expose ports. Either specify both ports (HOST:CONTAINER), or just the container port (a random host port will be chosen). So you redirect a host port (YOUR COMPUTER) to a container port*

So, in your particular example this should help:

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres

  web:
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/app
    build: ./testsite
    entrypoint: ./docker-entrypoint.sh
    volumes:
      - ./testsite:/var/app
    expose:
      - "80"
    depends_on:
      - db

  ngnix:
    restart: always
    build: ./ngnix
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./testsite/static:/staticimage
      - ./testsite/media:/mediafilesh
    depends_on:
      - web

  memcached:
    image: memcached:latest
    entrypoint:
      - memcached
      - -m 64
    ports:
      - "11211:11211" # This is only needed if you wants to connect from your host to the container
    expose:
      - "11211"
    depends_on:
      - web
```

Your cache settings:

```
CACHES = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
    'LOCATION': 'memcached:11211',
 }
}
```

Note that `memcached` is a reference to your memcached container in your `docker-compose.yml` file. For instance, if you named your memcached container like `my_project_memcached` you will need to use that name in your settings file.

```
my_project_memcached:
  image: memcached:latest
  entrypoint:
    - memcached
    - -m 64
  ports:
    - "11211:11211"
  expose:
    - "11211"
  depends_on:
    - web
```